# Passing Javascript global variable in HTML's <script> src attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script in my HTML head element.

```
<script src="" id="mapScriptID" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var resloc = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key="+key;
    var mapScript = document.getElementById('mapScriptID');
    mapScript.src = resloc;
</script>
```

The reason for it is that I would like the key value for the google map api to be defined in once only as I am using it in multiple places in my application. So that in the future when the key value changes I only have to change it in one place. But now for some reason the application is not seeing the google map api anymore. It's giving me '**google is not defined**' message when I call google.maps.LatLng(....);

it previously used to be

```
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And it worked completely fine.

Comment: Have a look to how to load js files dinamically. You should be able to use this this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: "It's giving me 'google is not defined' message when I call google.maps.LatLng(....);" — You don't appear to be doing that though. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the value for `key` set?

Comment: @phuzi in a separate .js file

Comment: @Quentin sorry about that. I meant when I used the library that I tagged in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple solutions. Eventually I used JQuery's $.getScript() method which worked sufficiently well in my scenario.